Notion of length in projective space over function field
Given a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ and two points $x, y \in \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$, the distance between $x$ and $y$ is defined as
$$
d(x, y) = \frac{\|v_x \wedge v_y\|}{\|v_x\| \|v_y\|}
$$
where $v_x$ and $v_y$ are non-zero vectors corresponding to $x$ and $y$, respectively. This expression is essentially the sine of the angle between the two lines in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.
My question is: If we instead work over the function field over a finite field, such as $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$, where there is no natural notion of angle, how can we define a "distance" between points in projective space?
As quadratic forms are well studied over the function field, I believe there might be some notion of distance. Any insight is very much appreciated.

It seems things make sense for every (complete?) normed field. Once a norm is fixed on $K^n$, there is not much than the choice of norm on $V\wedge V$ for $V=K^n$.

No, but I am asking in the real case, this $d(x,y)$ is nothing but $|\sin(x,y)|$, i.e., sine of the angle between two lines representing $x$ and $y$. In the function field, there is no such sense of angle; in fact the line also consists of just a bunch of points. Then what is the meaning of this distance intuitively? I guess $d(x,y)=|\sin(x,y)|$ does not make sense in this case right?

@YCor I am just not sure what does it signify as there is no notion of angle in the function field. If you can provide some insight.

Your definition of distance only depends on norms, not on any angle notion. If you have an ultrametric norm on $K$, you get, using the sup norm, a natural norm on $K^n$ and hence on $\bigwedge^2 K^n$.
